# TypeScript type for Apollo useMutation's refetchQueries?

Tags: typescript, apollo-client

I have an Apollo useMutation hook with TypeScript types:

```
const MY_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation($source: String!) {
    doSomething(source: $source) {
      result
    }
  }
`

const [myMutation] = useMutation<ReturnPayloadType, MutationVariables>(MY_MUTATION);
```

Which gives me type safety when I use it:

```
myMutation({
  variables: {
    source: 'some source',
    // foo: 'bar' This would error if uncommented. 
  }
})
```

This is working but now I need to use the `refetchQueries` key. How can I add types to it?

```
myMutation({
  variables: {
    source: 'some source',
    // foo: 'bar' This would error if uncommented. 
  },
  refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: MY_OTHER_QUERY,
      variables: {
        foo: 'bar' // I want to add type safety here
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer

You can't really. As of Apollo Client v3.4.0 `refetchQueries` is typed so that it eventually resolves to:

```
| "all"
| "active"
|  Array<string | DocumentNode | QueryOptions>`
```

The typings don't have a type parameter (generic) to allow you to specify your own typing for `refetchQueries`. I would rely on GraphQL's type guards at runtime and potentially type casting as a minor guard at compile time. You can cast the type of each object passed to `refetchQueries` to `QueryOptions` and specify the type of the variables via `QueryOption`'s type parameter. Type casting does have the caveat that you need to remember to use it and also it does not guarantee the types of the variables and query will match.

```
myMutation({
  variables: {
    source: 'some source',
    // foo: 'bar' This would error if uncommented. 
  },
  refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: MY_OTHER_QUERY,
      variables: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    } as QueryOptions<{ foo: string }>
  ]
})
```

## Long answer

As of Apollo Client v3.4.0 the `refetchQueries` option is typed as follows:

```
  refetchQueries?:
    | ((result: FetchResult<TData>) => InternalRefetchQueriesInclude)
    | InternalRefetchQueriesInclude;
```

– https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/release-3.4/src/core/watchQueryOptions.ts#L223-L225

where `InternalRefetchQueriesInclude` is typed as:

```
export type InternalRefetchQueriesInclude =
  | InternalRefetchQueryDescriptor[]
  | RefetchQueriesIncludeShorthand;
```

– https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/release-3.4/src/core/types.ts#L35-L37

and then the above essentially resolves to:

```
| "all"
| "active"
|  Array<string | DocumentNode | QueryOptions>`
```

– https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/release-3.4/src/core/types.ts#L26-L29

`QueryOptions` itself is typed [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/release-3.4/src/core/watchQueryOptions.ts#L46).

Throughout these types there is no type parameter (generic) to allow you to specify your own typing for `refetchQueries`. Although even if generics were available you'd need to solve the problem of trying to create a type that enforces "given an object with a property `query` of *type* we need another property `variables` with another *type*". Why is this important? Well, to answer that you need to ask what is the point of typing this? You want to ensure that if you use a given query any variables passed in that are the wrong type are caught at compile time instead of runtime and the risk of users encountering a bug is reduced. With functions it's easy because the identifier of the function and the identifier of the type are the same (it's built-in to functions that the type says "given this function it should have arguments of *type*") but in our case we don't have a function. As a result that's why I opened my answer with "you can't really".

I did explore the possibility of leveraging `typeof` as follows:

```
interface MyQueryNameRefetch extends QueryOptions {
  query: typeof MY_QUERY;
  variables: QueryVariables
}
```

In my original testing I only used const strings and incorrectly extrapolated the effect to the above possibility. Further testing showed this does not have the effect we want as only literal types and enum members don't widen their types when declared with or asserted to a `const`.

The closest you can get is typing the variables:

```
  refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: MY_OTHER_QUERY,
      variables: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    } as QueryOptions<{ foo: string }>
  ]
```

### Notes on Arvid's answer

At this point I want to touch on [@Arvid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11915236/arvid)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68639544/3050293). There's a function:

```
function typedQuery<TVariables>(
  options: QueryFunctionOptions<unknown, TVariables> & {
    query: TypedDocumentNode<unknown, TVariables>;
  },
) {
  return options;
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [myMutation] = useMutation<MyMutationPayloadType, MyMutationVariables>(MY_MUTATION);

  myMutation({
    variables: {
      source: 'a',
    },
    refetchQueries: [
      typedQuery<MyQueryVariables>({
        query: MY_QUERY,
        variables: {
          value: 1,
          // value: 'a' <-- gives compiler error
        },
      }),
    ],
  });
}
```

It's very similar to casting but it actually isn't a good idea. It shares the downsides of casting (you have to remember to use it); as well as additional ones such as having a runtime effect as the function will exist in compiled code as well as the call stack (your types should not have a runtime effect) and an effect on how the code is understood (functions convey some unit of runtime functionality but there is no runtime functionality here).

The root cause, again, comes down to the problem I described earlier about how the identifier and types are disconnected.

Comment: I have to disagree with your point about a function returning the given argument with a type being useless in general, it is virtually the same as the cast so that response seems a bit exaggerated. I do agree the cast is fine too and resorts in almost the same result.

I also think Apollo could do a much better job with their types. In my projects I've had to resolve to generated code but if TypeScript can at compile time [infer the TypeScript type of a Json Schema](https://github.com/ThomasAribart/json-schema-to-ts), it can certainly infer the types required for a refetch query.

Comment: I didn't say a function solely returning its argument is useless in general. I'm saying it's not a good idea when the reason is to get something typed correctly, especially when there are better constructs. TypeScript being able to understand GraphQL types is a separate problem. The issue is here is Apollo providing an interface to run a query which is an object with `query` and `variables` as properties. The whole point of typing this is to enforce variable types for a given query but there's no language construct to type this hence the interface and cast in my answer (short answer option 2).

Comment: FYI there has been an important change to my answer. The option referred to as "short answer option 2" does not work as intended. It will type your variables but cannot guarantee they will work with the specified query (the main point of typing these in the first place) and as a result add misdirection to anyone reading your code. I've updated my answer to reflect this as well as share why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Evanss: if you've used the proposed option already please change it to the other option, as per above comment.

Comment: @Arvid: I think this change confirms there is no language construct to type this properly (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not extremely familiar with Apollo, but you can solve your issue by adding a helper function. In the code below I've called it `typedQuery`. It might well be that Apollo has such a function already built in, but again, I don't know the library well enough for that.

```
import { gql, QueryFunctionOptions, TypedDocumentNode, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const MY_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation($source: String!) {
    doSomething(source: $source) {
      result
    }
  }
`;
type MyMutationPayloadType = { result: string };
type MyMutationVariables = {
  source: string;
};

const MY_QUERY = gql`
  query($value: Int!) {
    findSomething(value: $value) {
      someProperty
    }
  }
`;
type MyQueryVariables = {
  value: number;
};

function typedQuery<TVariables>(
  options: QueryFunctionOptions<unknown, TVariables> & {
    query: TypedDocumentNode<unknown, TVariables>;
  },
) {
  return options;
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [myMutation] = useMutation<MyMutationPayloadType, MyMutationVariables>(MY_MUTATION);

  myMutation({
    variables: {
      source: 'a',
    },
    refetchQueries: [
      typedQuery<MyQueryVariables>({
        query: MY_QUERY,
        variables: {
          value: 1,
          // value: 'a' <-- gives compiler error
        },
      }),
    ],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *awaitRefetchQueries¨ to wait the execution of the query:

```
awaitRefetchQueries: true,
refetchQueries: [
  {
    query: YOUR_QUERY,
  },
],
```